# How to vertically align an icon inside a span

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have a `span` like this:

```
<span class="indicator"></span>
```

Inside this `span` sometimes I have numbers like this:

```
<span class="indicator">
    <span>10</span>
</span>
```

And, sometimes some Kendo-UI icons, like this:

```
<span class="indicator">
    <span class="k-font-icon k-i-checkmark"></span>
</span>
```

And, here is my css:

```
span.indicator {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #8a8a8a;
    background: #8a8a8a;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.k-font-icon {
    font-family: KendoUIGlyphs;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    text-indent: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background-image: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

There are two problems:

1. I want the two `span` indicators to have the same heights. The height of
   the one with icon is one pixel more than the other one.
2. The icon in the `span` with icon is not vertically aligned.

**UPDATE:**

I realized if I change the `font-size` of `.k-font-icon` to `1em`, both issues will be resolved, but the icon will be too small.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's a Kendo UI [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OFARe).

Comment: can you add a pen with all the necessary resources? A 1px discrepancy is going to be hard to investigate otherwise.

Comment: @memo, the 1px difference is not as important as the icon not being vertically aligned. In fact, I managed to resolve the 1px difference by giving a fixed height to `.indicator`.

Comment: @memo, I added a Kendo UI Dojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're setting the height and with of your `.indicator`, there are a few ways you could do this, but the easiest is probably to change the display to `flex` instead of `inline-box` and add a couple of properties (I haven't added the vendor prefixes, mostly because I'm lazy…):

```
.indicator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #8a8a8a;
    background: #8a8a8a;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Unrelated side note:** unless you have an `.indicator` class that behaves different ways depending on what HTML element it's on (and if that's the case, you should probably refactor that) you shouldn't add a `span` at the beginning of you CSS rule. It increases the specificity for no reason and makes your CSS less flexible/future proof.

Answer (score 3):

```
.k-font-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Simplest way, hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) and [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) css:

```
  span.indicator {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #8a8a8a;
      background: #8a8a8a;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: .85em;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-family: helvetica;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 2px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      overflow: visible;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
  }
  span.indicator .k-font-icon {
    line-height: 20px !important;
  }
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/akxqvY)**

Comment: This also works. Thanks! I chose the other solution as the answer because it doesn't require styling `.k-font-icon`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

what about this?

```
span.indicator {
   background: #8a8a8a;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 1.35em;
   font-family: helvetica;
   padding: 2px;
   margin: 2px;
   width: 30px;
   overflow: visible;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

.k-font-icon {
    font-family: KendoUIGlyphs;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to use that font size for the number. It's too big. I can play with font sizes to make it vertically aligned, but that's not the solution I'm looking for. I need a solution that works without having to change the font sizes.